# Classes on the body tag are same after redirecting to other pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a new guy in the wordpress development town. I have mobius theme installed in wordpress. And implemented one child theme for that. I'm using style.css for styling all the pages. As i'm using one css for multiple pages I am checking the class on the body to ensure my styles will get applied on that page only. This is very important for me to have the required class with page id on the body tag. But all the classes are getting messed up after redirecting to any other page.

This is scenario happening with me.

Classes on the body present when visited home page for first time was:

```
'home page page-id-40 page-template-default'
```

After redirecting to other pages e.g. 'meet the team' page, I was expecting to have different classes. 'page page-id-1195 page-template-default'. But the classes on the body tags are unaffected.

But If I refresh the redirected page 'meet the team' I can see all the expected classes on the body tag.

Comment: Maybe the theme use ajax to load 'meet the team' page.

Comment: Yeah, that's why it't not loading css and js files required for that page too. I am adding style and js files based on the slug value in functions.php. But it's not executing at all. Is there anyway to disable ajax or preferred way to solve this problem.

Comment: The theme I was using is Mobius. I found that they had option an to load the content through ajax. Disabled that option and boom. I had almost 8 to 9 problems. That single toggle solved every single problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your theme is using ajax to load page content, you must follow the way it works when trying to implement custom style and javascript.

Your theme must have some javascript functions which trigger ajax call to get a new page and then replace the current page content with it. Find those functions and add your custom js based on the loaded page in its ajax callback function.

I see it is using jQuery, so you can refer to the documentation:

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Your style could be done the same way, but it's better to provide all custom styles during the first page load.